# select contact detail where People._ID = contact ID in android

Tags: android, contacts

I'm developing application in android. I have contactID, so how can I fetch particular People._ID record from contact list?

Answer (score 2):

If you use the new ContactsContract API:

```
String selection = ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID +" = ?";
String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{id}
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, selection, selectionArgs, null);
```

As you see, you have to use the selection- and selectionArgsParameters of the query-Methode to achieve the where clause.